# Prune list of pairs in R dataframe by removing redundancies based on genomic distance and p-value

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-manipulation

I have an R dataframe containing pairs of SNPs (with chromosome number and base pair location in separate columns) and p-values for each pair. The data looks like this:

```
chr_snp1     loc_snp1     chr_snp2     loc_snp2     pval
1            278474050    2            57386477     7.43e-08
1            275620856    2            57386662     1.08e-07
1            144075771    3            109909704    1.02e-06
1            144075771    3            111344453    2.06e-06
2            103701229    7            56369738     3.83e-08
2            102990566    7            56407691     1.07e-07
```

I want to remove redundancies in pairs. However, redundancy being defined as a similar pair that is close to another determined by the values in the `loc_snp1` and `loc_snp2` columns as well as `chr_snp1` and `chr_snp2`. The numeric limit I want to impose for values in `loc_snp1` and `loc_snp2` is 10,000,000 for pairs on the same combination of chromosomes. This data is sorted by chromosome (`chr_snp1` and `chr_snp2`), then base pair location (`loc_snp1` and `loc_snp2`), then by p-value (`pval`).

Basically I want the script to check if the value in `loc_snp1` is within 10,000,000 of the value in `loc_snp1` in the row above and if they both have the same value in `chr_snp1`. Then, also check if the value in `loc_snp2` is within 10,000,000 of the value in `loc_snp2` in the row above and if they both have the same value in `chr_snp2`. If all four conditions are true, only keep the row with the lowest pval and discard the other.

In order words, only keep the best pair and remove all the others that are close (have the same chromosome combination and within 10,000,000 base pairs of other pairs on their respective chromosomes).

This would result in the dataframe looking like:

```
chr_snp1     loc_snp1     chr_snp2     loc_snp2     pval
1            278474050    2            57386477     7.43e-08
1            144075771    3            109909704    1.02e-06
2            103701229    7            56369738     3.83e-08
```

Of course, the script doesn't have to actually check the row above. I assume there are more elegant ways to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is option. If you already know chr_snp1  and chr_snp2 need to be identical, you can start by grouping them and then calculating the the differences. Admittedly, this might fail if you have a duplicate chr_snp1 somewhere else in the dataset.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(chr_snp1, chr_snp2) |>
  mutate(grp = (abs(loc_snp1 - lag(loc_snp1, default = first(loc_snp1))) < 10e6) &
           (abs(loc_snp2 - lag(loc_snp2, default = first(loc_snp2))) < 10e6)) |>
  group_by(grp, .add=TRUE)  |>
  filter(pval == min(pval)) |>
  ungroup()|>
  select(-grp)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   chr_snp1  loc_snp1 chr_snp2  loc_snp2         pval
#>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1        1 278474050        2  57386477 0.0000000743
#> 2        1 144075771        3 109909704 0.00000102  
#> 3        2 103701229        7  56369738 0.0000000383
```

Comment: Chr_snp1 and Chr_snp2 can be identical but they absolutely can be different

Comment: Thats true. I meant that one of your conditions is that the chr_snp1  = the previous chr_snp1 .

Comment: Ah I see, yes I think that is true

Comment: This actually works extremely well. Do you have a good way to remove the "mirror" redundancies, e.g., |2 |57386662 |1 |278474050 |8.88E-07| & |1 |278474050 |2 |57386477 |7.43E-08| ?

Comment: What defines the "mirror"? I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: I posted an answer below. Essentially a mirror is a pair that if the chromosomal and bp pair positions were flipped, it would be removed using your code

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- textConnection('
chr_snp1, loc_snp1, chr_snp2, loc_snp2, pval
1, 278474050, 2, 57386477, 7.43e-08
1, 275620856, 2, 57386662, 1.08e-07
1, 194406449, 2, 182907442, 2.22e-06
1, 144075771, 3, 109909704, 1.02e-06
1, 144075771, 3, 111344453, 1.02e-06
2, 103701229, 7, 56369738, 1.02e-06
2, 102990566, 7, 56407691, 1.02e-06
') |> read.csv(header = TRUE)

# filter based on first 4 criteria
threshold <- 1e7
idx <- (
  ((diff(df$loc_snp1) |> abs()) <= threshold) &
    (diff(df$chr_snp1) == 0) &
    ((diff(df$loc_snp2) |> abs()) <= threshold) &
    (diff(df$chr_snp2) == 0)
) |> which()
df <- df[ idx, ]

# now retain only the pair with lowest p-value
df <- split(df, paste0(df$chr_snp1, df$chr_snp2)) |>
  lapply(function(x) {
    idx <- which.min(x$pval)
    x[ idx, ]
  }) |> 
  data.table::rbindlist() |> 
  as.data.frame()

# now retain only the pair with lowest p-value (mirror redundancies)
df <- split(df, paste0(df$chr_snp2, df$chr_snp1)) |>
  lapply(function(x) {
    idx <- which.min(x$pval)
    x[ idx, ]
  }) |> 
  data.table::rbindlist() |> 
  as.data.frame()

print(df)
```

```
  chr_snp1  loc_snp1 chr_snp2  loc_snp2     pval
1        1 278474050        2  57386477 7.43e-08
3        1 144075771        3 109909704 1.02e-06
5        2 103701229        7  56369738 1.02e-06
```

Comment: This works amazingly. Thank you. I just realized that redundancies can occur in another way:

|2 |57386662 |1 |278474050 |8.88E-07|
&
|1 |278474050 |2 |57386477 |7.43E-08

Is there a way to filter these "mirror" redundancies out as well?

Comment: LOL yup... see the edited post above for the laziest possible way to deal with mirror redundancies.

Comment: I'm also seeing another issue. There are instances where the chromosome combination is the same but the bp locations are different enough to be a new "good" pair. Here is an example:
|1 |278474050 |2 |57386477 |7.43E-08| & |1 |194406449 |2 |182907442 |2.22E-06 but it didn't show up in the final file. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited the sample code to include the record you mentioned. The reason it doesn't appear in the final results is because it does not satisfy the criteria...  |144075771-194406449|=50330678 which is > 1e7. You can verify with `diff(df$loc_snp1)`

Comment: Ah I think I see the issue. I want to retain pairs that are greater than 10e7 apart. That's because they are not close. Closeness is what I want to prune. The closer two SNPs are, the more likely they are in linkage disequilibrium and redundant

Comment: Also the math you provided above compares a pair that is on chr 1 and chr 2 to a pair that is on chr1 and chr3, they are not comparable

Comment: Apologies, I have to step away for a bit. Will take a closer look ASAP

Answer (score 0):

A friend was able to code how to handle mirror duplicates after AndS's initial pruning step.

```
Cart_Inter_Pruned$skip = FALSE
df = NULL
threshold = 10e7
for(i in 1:nrow(Cart_Inter_Pruned)){
  if(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,]$skip) next
  ordered_key1 = sort(array(unlist(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,c(1,3)])))
  
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(Cart_Inter_Pruned)){
    if(Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,]$skip) next
    ordered_key2 = sort(array(unlist(Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,c(1,3)])))
    if(paste(ordered_key1,collapse=",") == paste(ordered_key2,collapse = ",")){
      if_switch = ordered_key1[1] == ordered_key2[2]
      print(paste(i,j,ordered_key1))
      if(if_switch){
        if(abs(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,2]- Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,4]) <= threshold && abs(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,4] - Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,2]) <= threshold){
          Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,]$skip = TRUE
          Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,5] = min(as.numeric(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,5] ,as.numeric(Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,5])))
        }
      }else{
        if(abs(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,2]- Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,2]) <= threshold && abs(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,4] - Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,4]) <= threshold){
          Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,]$skip = TRUE
          Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,5] = min(as.numeric(Cart_Inter_Pruned[i,5] ,as.numeric(Cart_Inter_Pruned[j,5])))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```